# Using Newton's Method to solve $f(x)=x^2-2bx+b^2-d^2=0$

Tags: numerical-methods

What would be the Newton's method in the form $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$ to solve the equation $$f(x)=x^2-2bx+b^2-d^2=0$$ in which both $b>0,d>0$ are parameters? I also need to show that $|g'(x)|\le 1/2$ whenever $|x-b|\ge d/\sqrt{2}$ and also that $|g(x)-b|\ge d/\sqrt{2}$ whenever $|x-b|\ge d/\sqrt{2}$.

Haven't really broken ice with this problem. Hopefully someone here can help me. Also, I understand that Newton's method is unneeded in this problem for the first part, but that's what the question asks for.

Comment: For a given function $h$, how does the iteration for Newton's method look like?

Comment: @Roland It goes $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{h(x_n)}{h'(x_n)}$$

Comment: So if we put $g(x)= x - \frac{h(x)}{h'(x)}$ then $x_{x+1}= g(x_n)$, correct? How do we translate this back for our problem for $f$? Can we write down $g$ more explicitely?

Comment: @Roland I can't figure it out

Comment: Newton's method is not needed but it's a test to see whether you can handle Newton's Method. E.g, if you put specific values for b,d then you can tell whether you did it right because you haave another method to find x.

Comment: $x_{n+1}=x_n-f((x_n)/f'(x_n)$ as user312787 said, but (s)he siad $h$,not$ f.$  For a quadratic $f$ , and with $f'(x_0)\ne 0$, the sequence $(x_k)_k$ will converge to a zero of $f$.This can be shown with  the help a diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The iteration for Newton's method is $x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'{x_n}}$, i.e. if we need to find a function $g$ which describes the iteration, then we can take $$g(x)= x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}.$$

Here, knowledge about $g$ means knowledge about the sequence $x_{n+1}=g^n(x_0)$, i.e. area and rate of convergence of the series which is supposed to converge to a root of $f$. Since $f(x)= x^2 - 2bx +b^2 - d^2, $ we find $f'(x)= 2x -2b$.

Inserting this in the formula above, we get $$g(x)= x - \frac{x^2 - 2bx +b^2 - d^2}{2x - 2b}= \frac{2x^2 - 2bx  - x^2 + 2bx - b^2 + d^2 }{2x - 2b}= \frac{x^2 -b^2 + d^2}{2x -2b}.$$

With this formula for $g$, can you tackle the questions?